# Tabindexes when answering

Tags: discussion, bug

I was trying to answer a question, and then out of habit, I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to 'deindent' some code. Of course this doesn't work in the editor, but what happened is that apparently the search in the headerbar suddenly gained focus and started to grow.

I honestly would have expected that a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the editor would result in either deindenting of the text, or if using tab indexes that one of the toolbar buttons (undo/redo) would gain focus.

This happened in Chrome 62.0.3202.94 on Windows 7 Professional.

Is this a bug or a feature request? I'm not sure, but I'm leaning towards a bug.

Comment: Looks like normal tab order to me, there isn't anything else to tab to between the post box and the header.  The big jump is a big disconcerting I suppose, that's all.

Comment: Tabs in the editor are not affecting indentation, no. The search box just happens to be the preceding element in the focus order, I'm pretty sure that that is by design.

Comment: There are only three `tabindex` attributes set. The search field has index 1, the answer field has index 101, and the answer submit button has index 110. So what you're seeing is intentional, but the question is whether it's desirable.

Comment: Changing the editor so we can use tabs to indent/deindent code would be a feature request, and certainly one I would support. However, currently, you're a bit vague in what you want to happen. Tab is the standard key to change input controls in HTML, so it doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth When i'm typing an answer, i'm focussed on the editor, and technically the buttons on the editor window are also input elements from my viewpoint as user, hence my expectation that when I use shift tab and it doesn't deindent code that it jumps to those buttons and that I could use those and a space key to press and than tab back to the editor, instead of the search element.